# Question on Volume of Box in $K \otimes \mathbb{R}$, with $K$ a Number Field

Tags: calculus, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading over the proof of Hermite's result that only finitely many number fields have a discriminant with $|\Delta_K| = \Delta  \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. What I am stuck on is the following: consider the box
\begin{equation}
B = \{(x_1, \dots, x_{r_1}, x_{r_1+1}, \dots x_{r_1+ r_2}): |x_1| < 1+\sqrt{\Delta}, |x_2|, \dots |x_{r_1+r_2}| < 1 \} \subset K \otimes \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings of $K$ and $2r_2$ is the number of complex ones. I want to prove that $\text{vol}(B) = 2^{r_1}\pi^{r_2}(1+\sqrt{\Delta})$. My attempts so far have been trying to do a change of variables on a volume integral for $B$, but I keep getting lost as to how to produce the factor $\pi^{r_2}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn’t you tensor with $\mathbb C$ or more comply just throw together the embeddings - I’m confused by your norms. If I remember correctly, there is a change of variable. The complex pieces produce the $\pi$’s because the set $|z|<R$ for complex $z$ is a circle.

Comment: Perhaps the fact you're missing is that $K\otimes \mathbb R$ is naturally a subring of $\mathbb R^{r_1}\times\mathbb C^{r_2}$. So you can just calculate the areas as you would in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. There should be no need to do any crazy integrals.

Comment: @TokenToucan Tensoring with $\mathbb R$ is the correct way to get the product of real and complex embeddings. Tensoring with $\mathbb C$ will get a subring of $\mathbb C^{r_1 + 2r_2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the direct product of an interval of length $2(1+\sqrt{\Delta})$
(namely $[-(1+\sqrt{\Delta}),1+\sqrt{\Delta}]$) with $r_1-1$ intervals
of length two (namely $[-1,1]$) and $r_2$ unit discs in the
complex plane (so each of volume $\pi$).

The volume is
$$2(1+\sqrt\Delta)2^{r_1-1}\pi^{r_2}.$$

Comment: Why are we allowed to directly multiply all these numbers together? Is there a certain result I am missing?

Comment: Fubini's theorem?